# How do I make ion-menu-button larger?

Tags: ionic4

How do I make the ion-menu-button (hamburger menu button) larger?

The ion-menu-button component creates an ion-icon with font-size set to 26px. There is no attribute to set size and CSS seems to have no impact.

[UPDATE]
I reported this as a bug to the Ionic team and they "fixed" it here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/18667 although i still don't see how to modify the size.

setting:

```
ion-icon {
  --font-size: 100px !important;
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

does nothing

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it out on my own. There was a

```
.sc-ion-buttons-md-h {
  display: flew;
}
```

wrapper that was limiting the size of the button. Once i removed that:

```
.sc-ion-buttons-md-h {
  display: block !important;
}
```

and used ion-grid to place button on the left side of my header, i could then use:

```
ion-menu-button {
  font-size: 50px !important;
}
```

to set the size of my menu button.